# iPhone - Draw some text with CGContext : ok but... mirrored

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, text, core-graphics, transformation

When I draw some text using CGContext, it is drawn mirrored.

I tried to apply some transformations, then it is draw well, but then the rest of the drawing and all coordinates seems to be draw bad.

I tried to save and restore the context, before and ater drawing the text (and aplying transformation), but that does not help.

How some text must be drawn onto a View using CGContext without affecting the rest of the drawing, nor the onscreen CGPoint coords for that text ?

Comment: I also get mirrored text on Y axis. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can you clarify what you mean as 'mirrored'?  Here is some code for drawing some black text.  It should not be 'mirrored'.

```
CGRect viewBounds = self.bounds;
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, viewBounds.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.0);
CGContextSelectFont(ctx, "Helvetica", 10.0, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetCharacterSpacing(ctx, 1.7);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(ctx, kCGTextFill);
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(ctx, 100.0, 100.0, "SOME TEXT", 9);
```

Comment: That's really near what I do. I'll try tonight your piece of code.

Comment: because of CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

Comment: CGContextShowTextAtPoint @deprecated since iOS 7.0

Comment: yes, CGContextShowTextAtPoint is not working, any solution with drawing a text to a specific CGContextRef?

Comment: `NSString` has a category `UIStringDrawing`, there are many text drawing functions, ex: `drawInRect:withFont:`. They will draw in the current context.

Answer (score 9):

I think you have to reverse the text matrix :

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, transform);
```

Comment: Thanks for this easy solution! Worked like a charm.